# Issue coming in constraint using Fluent API EF Code First

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

**I have 2 classes.**

```
public class Om_MembershipCharges
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 MembershipChargesID { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public Int16 PerMonth { get; set; }
    public Int16? MemebershipTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Om_MembershipType MemebershipType { get; set; }
}

public class Om_MembershipType
{
    [Key]
    public Int16 MemebershipTypeID { get; set; }
    public String MemebershipType { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsDefaultMembership { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Om_MembershipCharges> MembershipCharges { get; set; }
}
```

**Database Models are below.**

```
public MembershipTypeMap()
{
    Property(x => x.MemebershipTypeID)
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(x => x.MemebershipType)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(100)
        .HasColumnAnnotation
        (
            IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
            new IndexAnnotation
            (
                new IndexAttribute("U_MembershipType", 1) { IsUnique = true }
            )
        );

    Property(x => x.IsDefaultMembership).IsRequired();
    ToTable(clsCommon.tblMembershipType);
}


public class MembershipChargesMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Om_MembershipCharges>
{
    public MembershipChargesMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.MembershipChargesID);

        Property(x => x.Amount).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.PerMonth).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.MemebershipTypeID).IsOptional();    
        ToTable(clsCommon.tblMembershipCharges);
    }
}
```

**Finally below are the Constraints**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Om_MembershipCharges>()
       .HasOptional(x => x.MemebershipType)
       .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.MemebershipTypeID)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


modelBuilder.Entity<Om_MembershipCharges>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.MemebershipType).WithMany(m => m.MembershipCharges)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.MembershipChargesID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**I am facing below exception** Anyone faced this kind of issue before ?

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Om_MembershipCharges_MemebershipType_Source: : Multiplicity is not
>   valid in Role 'Om_MembershipCharges_MemebershipType_Source' in
>   relationship 'Om_MembershipCharges_MemebershipType'. Because the
>   Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the
>   multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
>   Om_MembershipCharges_MemebershipType_Target_Om_MembershipCharges_MemebershipType_Source:
>   : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential
>   constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the
>   Principal Role. The type of property 'MembershipChargesID' on entity
>   'Om_MembershipCharges' does not match the type of property
>   'MemebershipTypeID' on entity 'Om_MembershipType' in the referential
>   constraint 'Om_MembershipCharges_MemebershipType'.

Comment: What is the intended relationship between your entities?

Comment: I want to see all membership charges records from membership type table. and I want to see one membership type from Membership Charges table

Comment: Is the `WithMany` in the first constraint intentional? If it's a FK, there can be only one.

Comment: I think I am missing something in the constraint or I am doing something wrong. Kindly do the corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last code snippet...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Om_MembershipCharges>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.MemebershipType).WithMany(m => m.MembershipCharges)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.MembershipChargesID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

...overwrites the previous registration of `m.MembershipType` and now makes it required, which EF expresses by saying that its multiplicity should be `1`, not `0..1`.

Seeing the navigation properties, the mapping should be a merger of the two last snippets (note the `HasOptional`). *And* you should use `MembershipTypeID` in stead of `MembershipChargesID`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Om_MembershipCharges>()
    .HasOptional(m => m.MemebershipType).WithMany(m => m.MembershipCharges)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.MembershipTypeID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Side note: I would put all mapping code into the mapping classes. It's easier for maintenance to keep it together. I thinkf you're even required to do so, because EF won't allow you to register the `EntityTypeConfiguration`s besides registering the types by `modelBuilder.Entity<T>`.

Comment: Thank You for the very quick response. I am still facing the same issue. No Luck so far.

Comment: Is this better? By the way: are you actually registering the EntityTypeConfigurations as well?

Comment: Yes sir EntityTypeConfigurations  are being done. I am sttill facing the same problem. Kindly edit the answer with all classes and mapping done like in the question. Seems like I am missing something.